# rayPlaneIntersection (like) exemple or similar function

Tags: math, view, artificial-intelligence, bots, ray

I'm working with bots in Call Of Duty and their vision is calculated with a bulletTracePassed  function, there's no other way to calculate that, since there's not really bot functions, so this will return true if a bullet can pass from point A to point B returning true/false, which work﻿s great MOST of the times, but cause﻿s a chaos in those 2 cases mainly:

1. When the mapper didn't put any kind iDFLAGS_PENETRATION on the walls (means the wall have no resistance to bullets, so there's not contact/hit, and the bullets pass through like was nothing.
2. When we have Trees, Plants, etc in the middle

In those 2﻿ cases the bots will see ﻿the other players ﻿when shoudn't, and in jungle like maps it's a complete hell to play.

Ok, the right way to do these fixes are just fix the maps, adding the right penetration in those walls and dense vegetation, but is not possible do that because are SEVERAL maps by SEVERAL modders, and even official releases with the same problems, and of course, we don't have their sources to apply these fixes.

So the only way to do that is via script, and I'm thinking in doing something like this:

I have the position of the eye of the attacker bot in 3D like (x,y,z) for exemple (1000,500,22), and also the position which hit the other players like (2000,1200,60), which is returned by the function bulletTracePassed.

But for exemple, in a wall I have part of it without any collision, so the bots can see through them, so would like to set the middle of the wall with position (1600,800,50) and angles (10,-40,-90) and a square radius of the size to of the square/plane, for exemple, 500.

So I want to test if the ray passed through this square/plane, then returning false/true to let me use it to make the bots decide to aim to shoot or not this player behind the "bad" wall.

Looking around I found the function rayPlaneIntersection, which by the name seams what I want, but didn't get right yet how it works in my solution, since I can't see any kind of angles of even a square radius to determine their size... or are doing to a single point only?

```
rayPlaneIntersectionrayPlaneIntersection(ray0: vec3, ray1: vec3, origin?: vec3 | number[], normal?: vec3 | number[]): vec3 | undefined

Defined in raymath.ts:130

Computes the intersection point of a given ray and a given plane (rooted at [ 0, 0, 0 ]). t = -(dot(plane.xyz, origin) + plane.w) / dot(plane.xyz, ray); The ray intersects when (t > 0.0) && (t < tm) is true.

Parameters

ray0: vec3 Start point of a ray.
ray1: vec3Far point of a ray, used to derive the ray direction.
Default value origin: vec3 | number[] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Point on a plane with origin [ 0, 0, 0 ].
Default value normal: vec3 | number[] = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
Normal of the plane with origin [ 0, 0, 0 ].
Returns vec3 | undefined
If ray intersects, the intersection point on the plane if the plane was hit.
```

Anyone could point an exemple of this use in my exemple? Or any other function that might give me the same (or even similar) result to let me at least start to fix this problem?
I know it's not an easy task, that's why I'm posting here, after many lost hours trying to do it alone without success yet.

thank you very much.